# Spring configuration with filter chain

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-saml

I used the spring security using saml from this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/tree/master/sample

Now I have my own JSP pages with controller, when I add it to the project, it is stating 404. when try to access `http://localhost:2/SAMPLE/pop`

My JSP at `WEB-INF-jsp-pop.jsp`

```
@Controller
public class ComCont {
@RequestMapping(value="/pop",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showHomePage(Map<Object, Object> model) {
    System.out.println("gotach");
    return "pop";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/hello",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showHomePage1(Map<Object, Object> model) {
    System.out.println("gotach");
    return "hello";
}
```

}

My servlet context is

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

securityContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Enable auto-wiring -->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <!-- Scan for auto-wiring classes in spring saml packages -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.security.saml"/>

    <!-- Unsecured pages -->
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/favicon.ico"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/images/**"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/css/**"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/logout.jsp"/>

    <!-- Security for the administration UI -->
    <security:http pattern="/saml/web/**" use-expressions="false">
        <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/saml/web/metadata/login"/>
        <security:form-login login-processing-url="/saml/web/login" login-page="/saml/web/metadata/login" default-target-url="/saml/web/metadata"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/metadata/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
    </security:http>

    <!-- Secured pages with SAML as entry point -->
    <security:http entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint" use-expressions="false">
       <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>

        <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
        <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
    </security:http>

    <!-- Filters for processing of SAML messages -->
    <bean id="samlFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <security:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/login/**" filters="samlEntryPoint"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/logout/**" filters="samlLogoutFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/metadata/**" filters="metadataDisplayFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSO/**" filters="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSOHoK/**" filters="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SingleLogout/**" filters="samlLogoutProcessingFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/discovery/**" filters="samlIDPDiscovery"/>
        </security:filter-chain-map>
    </bean>

    <!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login -->
    <bean id="successRedirectHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/"/>
    </bean>
    <!--
    Use the following for interpreting RelayState coming from unsolicited response as redirect URL:
    <bean id="successRedirectHandler" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLRelayStateSuccessHandler">
       <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/" />
    </bean>
    -->

    <!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after failed login -->
    <bean id="failureRedirectHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <property name="useForward" value="true"/>
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/error.jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Handler for successful logout -->
    <bean id="successLogoutHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/logout.jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <!-- Register authentication manager for SAML provider -->
        <security:authentication-provider ref="samlAuthenticationProvider"/>
        <!-- Register authentication manager for administration UI -->
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service id="adminInterfaceService">
                <security:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <!-- Logger for SAML messages and events -->
    <bean id="samlLogger" class="org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger"/>

    <!-- Central storage of cryptographic keys -->
    <bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
        <constructor-arg value="classpath:security/samlKeystore.jks"/>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="nalle123"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="apollo" value="nalle123"/>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="apollo"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from properties file -->
    <bean id="samlEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint">
        <property name="defaultProfileOptions">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
                <property name="includeScoping" value="false"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- IDP Discovery Service -->
    <bean id="samlIDPDiscovery" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLDiscovery">
        <property name="idpSelectionPath" value="/WEB-INF/security/idpSelection.jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Filter automatically generates default SP metadata -->
    <bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
                <property name="extendedMetadata">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                        <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="true"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with filterSuffix and presents SP metadata there -->
    <bean id="metadataDisplayFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter"/>

    <!-- Configure HTTP Client to accept certificates from the keystore for HTTPS verification -->
    <!--
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolConfigurer">
        <property name="sslHostnameVerification" value="default"/>
    </bean>
    -->

    <!-- IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of trust is here -->
    <bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <!-- Example of classpath metadata with Extended Metadata -->
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
                            <constructor-arg>
                                <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
                            </constructor-arg>
                            <constructor-arg>
                                <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                                    <constructor-arg value="/metadata/idp.xml"/>
                                </bean>
                            </constructor-arg>
                            <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
                <!-- Example of HTTP metadata without Extended Metadata -->
                <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
                    <!-- URL containing the metadata -->
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <value type="java.lang.String">http://localhost:12/idp-meta.xml</value>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <!-- Timeout for metadata loading in ms -->
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <value type="int">15000</value>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                </bean>
                <!-- Example of file system metadata without Extended Metadata -->
                <!--
                <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <value type="java.io.File">/usr/local/metadata/idp.xml</value>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                </bean>
                -->
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
        <!-- OPTIONAL used when one of the metadata files contains information about this service provider -->
        <!-- <property name="hostedSPName" value=""/> -->
        <!-- OPTIONAL property: can tell the system which IDP should be used for authenticating user by default. -->
        <!-- <property name="defaultIDP" value="http://localhost:8080/opensso"/> -->
    </bean>

    <!-- SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received SAML messages -->
    <bean id="samlAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider">
        <!-- OPTIONAL property: can be used to store/load user data after login -->
        <!--
        <property name="userDetails" ref="bean" />
        -->
    </bean>

    <!-- Provider of default SAML Context -->
    <bean id="contextProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl"/>

    <!-- Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages -->
    <bean id="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureRedirectHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Processing filter for WebSSO Holder-of-Key profile -->
    <bean id="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureRedirectHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Logout handler terminating local session -->
    <bean id="logoutHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler">
        <property name="invalidateHttpSession" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Override default logout processing filter with the one processing SAML messages -->
    <bean id="samlLogoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
        <constructor-arg index="2" ref="logoutHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Filter processing incoming logout messages -->
    <!-- First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful global logout -->
    <bean id="samlLogoutProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Class loading incoming SAML messages from httpRequest stream -->
    <bean id="processor" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <ref bean="redirectBinding"/>
                <ref bean="postBinding"/>
                <ref bean="artifactBinding"/>
                <ref bean="soapBinding"/>
                <ref bean="paosBinding"/>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
    <bean id="webSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
    <bean id="hokWebSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile -->
    <bean id="webSSOprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile -->
    <bean id="hokWebSSOProfile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 ECP profile -->
    <bean id="ecpprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileECPImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Logout Profile -->
    <bean id="logoutprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfileImpl"/>

    <!-- Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing messages -->
    <bean id="postBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPostBinding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="redirectBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="artifactBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPArtifactBinding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager"/>
                        </constructor-arg>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="processor">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
                        <constructor-arg ref="soapBinding"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="soapBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPSOAP11Binding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="paosBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPAOS11Binding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Initialization of OpenSAML library-->
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap"/>

    <!-- Initialization of the velocity engine -->
    <bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory" factory-method="getEngine"/>

    <!-- XML parser pool needed for OpenSAML parsing -->
    <bean id="parserPool" class="org.opensaml.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool" init-method="initialize">
        <property name="builderFeatures">
            <map>
                <entry key="http://apache.org/xml/features/dom/defer-node-expansion" value="false"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="parserPoolHolder" class="org.springframework.security.saml.parser.ParserPoolHolder"/>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>saml</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>saml</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/saml/web/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

What is I'm missing here? I'm new to Spring MVC. I know some basics.

Comment: Enable `DEBUG` logs for Spring to see where the request is being processed.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem.Are you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

**URL pattern Syntax :**

```
http://localhost:2/{Your project_name}/{url-pattern}/{jsp name}
```

Try to hit this url,

```
http://localhost:2/SAMPLE/saml/web/pop
```

else, Change your `dispatcher-servlet` Servlet mapping to like this,

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>saml</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now try this url, `http://localhost:2/SAMPLE/pop`

Change your Controller RequestMapping to like this,

```
@Controller
public class ComCont {

   @RequestMapping(value="/pop",method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public String showHomePage(Map<Object, Object> model) {
      System.out.println("gotach");
      return "pop";
   }
}
```

Comment: It is very tricky. If I try to hit `http://localhost:8080/SAMPLE/saml/web/pop` it is redirecting to local web login as it is mentioned in `<!-- Security for the administration UI -->` If I change `dispatcher-servlet` my saml configurations won't work. So I need to add a pages under saml filter chain like you can seee at ` <!-- Secured pages with SAML as entry point -->`

Comment: Then change your controller RequestMapping. Check my updated answer

Comment: Other than this `/saml/web/*` pattern, everything moved to `org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy` so `filter-chain` needs to be configured. This is what I figured out from my knowledge. But not sure how to do, or it is correct. :(

Comment: `springSecurityFilterChain` configured is correct in your xml. Which spring version are you using?

Comment: It is 3.1.2 it is not configured right, it is configured for `/saml/login` not for `/saml/**` can you pls take a look at it.?

Comment: Spring security 3.1 above version different from older version.

Comment: This is the jar that I'm using `spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the content you have provided for `web.xml` and `securityContext.xml`, they looks fine, so doesn't look like filter chain issue. **Moreover you are getting 404 which means there is some issue with URL**, if you were getting 5xx then it could have been because of some server issue like filter chain. Or 403 if it was because of security or access issue. Below are details on resolution:

Assuming you do have (must be having) `saml-servlet.xml`, use below instead of what you have provided:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Based on above, you can understand (I think you are already doing) that you need to have your JSP's in `/WEB-INF/jsp/`

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve from your controller code but if you are trying to render your `pop.jsp` from the URL you mentioned then use below code in controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/pop",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showHomePage(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("I am in pop .. Lets rock ..");
    return new ModelAndView("pop", "pop", "I am coming from controller");
}
```

Three arguments to `ModelAndView` constructor

1. Name of JSP, this case Spring will resolve it as `pop.jsp` and should be located under `/WEB-INF/jsp/`
2. Name of the object you want to pass to the JSP page, in this case name of the object is "pop", so you can use `${pop}` in your JSP and you will see "I am coming from controller" getting rendered. This is just a String but you can pass a POJO which can be accessed using JSON notation in your JSP.
3. Actual object, String in this case.

Now, coming to your URL - `http://localhost:2/SAMPLE/pop`, I am pretty sure that you know this but I feel responsible to cover this, so - your WAR file name should be `SAMPLE.war` because that's your web context. If it is not then you have to use same name, lets say for `springapp.war`, your URL will be `http://localhost:2/springapp`. This is basic part of your URL.

Now you were using `http://localhost:2/SAMPLE/pop` which by all means is incorrect because your `DispatcherServlet` is configured for URL mapping of `/saml/web/*`. So, all your web request should have URL as `http://localhost:2/SAMPLE/saml/web/`. Whatever is the `DispatcherServlet` mapping should come after your URL context path - `http://localhost:2/SAMPLE`

Now, if you want to hit the `/pop` controller then you have start building your URL after `DispatcherServlet` mapping, so your URL will become `http://localhost:2/SAMPLE/saml/web/pop`.
If you use exact above URL and do the code modifications as I suggested then I am positive that your "pop.jsp" will be displayed.

Please note that your controller method is accepting only GET requests - `RequestMethod.GET`, so you have to hit the URL from browser. In case if you are sending Ajax POST requests from JSP then controller mapping should have `RequestMethod.POST`.
Also, please take care of using exact URL while taking care of slashes `/`

Comment: Did you give a try to this ??